# Convert string(array format) to array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have string which is in the format of array..I have to convert this as array in php

```
"[["S.No","Date","Particulars","Vch Type","Vch No.","Debit Amount","Credit Amount"],["1","2017-06-20","Purchase-Germany VISA","Card Payment(Kanara)","45","48,879","-"],["2","2017-06-20","Purchase-Thailand VISA","Card Payment(Kanara)","12","46,664","-"],["3","2017-06-20","Purchase-Germany VISA","Card Payment(SBI)","32423","8,558","-"],["4","2017-06-20","Purchase-Germany VISA","CP","3455","21,323","-"],null,["5","2017-06-20","Purchase-Singapore VISA","CP","11111","10,000","-"],["6","2017-06-20","Purchase-Singapore VISA","BP","11111","500","-"],["7","2017-06-20","Purchase-Germany VISA","Card Payment(Kanara)","12345","2,464","-"],["8","2017-06-20","Purchase-Germany VISA","Card Payment(Axis)","12345","1,350","-"]]"
```

I have to put it in csv file..i tried this..but no use..

```
 $getdata= "above string";
 $exceldata = json_decode($_REQUEST['getdata'], true); 

 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=demo.csv');
 $data = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach((array)$exceldata as $arr){
  fputcsv($data,array($arr);
}
```

Comment: And what did you try yet?

Comment: @Bernhard Check my edited question

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the CSV file path on `$data = fopen('php://output', 'w');`

Just replace

```
$data = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

With

```
$data = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
```

You can check [fputcsv.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your string should have backslash

```
"[[\"S.No\",\"Date\",\"Particulars\",\"Vch Type\",\"Vch No.\",\"Debit Amount\",\"Credit Amount\"],[\"1\",\"2017-06-20\",\"Purchase-Germany VISA\",\"Card Payment(Kanara)\",\"45\",\"48,879\",\"-\"],[\"2\",\"2017-06-20\",\"Purchase-Thailand VISA\",\"Card Payment(Kanara)\",\"12\",\"46,664\",\"-\"],[\"3\",\"2017-06-20\",\"Purchase-Germany VISA\",\"Card Payment(SBI)\",\"32423\",\"8,558\",\"-\"],[\"4\",\"2017-06-20\",\"Purchase-Germany VISA\",\"CP\",\"3455\",\"21,323\",\"-\"],null,[\"5\",\"2017-06-20\",\"Purchase-Singapore VISA\",\"CP\",\"11111\",\"10,000\",\"-\"],[\"6\",\"2017-06-20\",\"Purchase-Singapore VISA\",\"BP\",\"11111\",\"500\",\"-\"],[\"7\",\"2017-06-20\",\"Purchase-Germany VISA\",\"Card Payment(Kanara)\",\"12345\",\"2,464\",\"-\"],[\"8\",\"2017-06-20\",\"Purchase-Germany VISA\",\"Card Payment(Axis)\",\"12345\",\"1,350\",\"-\"]]";
```